# Manipulate iOS device's Wi-Fi programmatically

Tags: python, ios, selenium, networking, appium

I am writing in automation script in xcode using Python, appium, and  selenium and I need to be able to toggle WiFi on and off and switch to a different saved Network on a real iOS device. Is this possible? Maybe I can use surprocess to open Settings>Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, I was able to do this as below:

```
 @Test
    public void testUntitled() {
        driver.executeScript("client:client.swipe(\"Down\", 0, 500)");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Wi-Fi']")).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("((((//*[@text=' ']/*/*/*[@class='UIAView' and ./parent::*[@class='UIAView' and ./parent::*[@class='UIAWindow']]])[3]/*[@class='UIAView'])[1]/*[@class='UIAView'])[1]/*[@class='UIAView' and @width>0])[1]")));
        driver.executeScript("client:client.swipe(\"Up\", 0, 500)");
    }
```

Below is how it looked on the physical device

[image]

Sorry, since I don't know python. But I hope you'll be able to modify java to python easily.

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up doing. Thank you for your answer and all the effort you put in! Oh and by the way you've two text messages

Comment: And for anyone else viewing this in the future, in order to switch Wi-Fi's, I pulled down from the top of the screen and search for settings and navigated to the Wi-Fi I needed.